# Cannot find SQL Server : SqlConnection problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

[image]

It's my first time and I checked it in the internet and I followed every step but I have a problem here in `SqlConnection` I think its says that it cannot find the SQL Server and  don't know why.

I'm trying to make a simple Employees data (with a photo and date) and I want to save it to SQL Server. At first, I created a new SQL Server and put `(localdb)\MSSQLocalDB` as the Server Name, and `EmployeeDatabase`" as the new database name.

I got the Connection String in the properties of the database and this is what I got

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=USER_TABLE;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
```

I get this error when using this connection string:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -  Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace EmployeeDataSystem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Insert_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=USER_TABLE;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Personnel(Id,EmployeeName,EmployeeBirthdate,EmployeeSalary,EmployeeAddress,EmployeeMobile,EmployeeHiredate,EmployeePhoto) VALUES (@Id,@EmployeeName,@EmployeeBirthdate,@EmployeeSalary,@EmployeeAddress,@EmployeeMobile,@EmployeeHiredate,@EmployeePhoto)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(Id_number.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", int.Parse(Employee_name.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeBirthdate", dateTimePicker1.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeSalary", int.Parse(Salary_textbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeAddress", int.Parse(Address_textbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeMobile", int.Parse(Mobile_textbox.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeHiredate", dateTimePicker2.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeePhoto", pictureBox1.Image);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            Id_number.Text = "";
            Employee_name.Text = "";
            //dateTimePicker1.Value = "";
            Salary_textbox.Text = "";
            Address_textbox.Text = "";
            Mobile_textbox.Text = "";
            //dateTimePicker2.Value = "";
            //pictureBox1.Image = "";

            MessageBox.Show("Successfullly Inserted!");
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            PictureBox p = sender as PictureBox;

            if(p != null)
            {
                open.Filter = "(*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp;";

                if(open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    p.Image = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your photo is hardly readable. Please post the expection message as text.

Comment: Thank you here:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

Comment: You should [edit] your question and put this information directly in the question (instead of the photo).

Comment: first check the instance of MSSQL server is  correct or not and check the MSSQL setting if the Remote connection is allowed or not

Comment: Thank you I have already checked it and the Remote Connection is already allowed

Answer (score 1):

if use default instanst sql server use from dot(.) As datasource else use instansname that you can find  through server name in sql server

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=your instance name;Initial Catalog=databasename;User Id=your user;Password=your password;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
```

find your instance name
[image]
and select a login name for remote to sql server
[image]
and click on your user and  do setting user
[image]
[image]

Comment: I already tried it and it didn't work. Right now I'm downloading SQL Server Management Studio, is it necessary?

Comment: What is your default instans name? Are you add login in sql server?are you sql server mixed mod enable?

Comment: I think it is /MSSQLLocalDB ,yes sql server mixed mod enable

Comment: i updated my answer please do this answer if you have problem say me

Comment: if you have problem upload photo from sql server engin name

Comment: Hello thanks for the help!! There is an error about the upload photo from SQL Server **'No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type.'**                                                                                                Do you think `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeePhoto", pictureBox1.Image);` this is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Initial Catalog=EmployeeDatabase

If you are unsure of your instance name(**Data Source**) do the following:

1. Open a command prompt window
2. services.msc
3. Locate the entries beginning with SQL.
   There will be an entry for each instance called SQL Server (instancename). The instance name appears within the parentheses.

Comment: And check if Sql Server service is Running.

Comment: It is running but there is only SQL Server VVS Writer

Answer (score 1):

in your picture the connection string is

```
 "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=USER_TABLE;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
```

change it to

```
"Data Source=.\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=USER_TABLE;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
```

Comment: The Backslash Before MSSQLLocalDB has red underline/error that says 'Unrecognized escape sequence'



Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1009 Unrecognized escape sequence EmployeeDataSystem C:\Users\siych\OneDrive\Desktop\Employee Data System\EmployeeDataSystem\EmployeeDataSystem\Form1.cs 62 Active

Comment: use \\ instead of \ and again try a chance

Comment: `instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'`

Comment: can you take a picture from SQL server that you connected it

Comment: Hello I already got it thanks for the help!! here:
`SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source =(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = USER_TABLE; Integrated Security = True; Pooling = False");`

Answer (score 0):

try to use . (dot) as the instance name